# From local server to web hosting

Tags: migrations

I have created a website on local with bitnami. Now I want to upload it to a web server (probably on hostgator).

I don't care about content. The site is empty and I will add content only when I upload it.

I just want to keep the settings, permissions, content types and modules. So, I can start add content on air.

If I copy paste the htdocs folder with ftp in the server, this will work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way, (used to do all this useless stuff before GIT and capistrano...)

Copy/upload **all** (hidden) the **contents** of your Drupal folder in the public_html or whatever your server document root is for that site.

Export your local database in a dump file.

Create a mysql database on the live server, import the local dump.

Edit the sites/default/settings.php file on your live server to serve your new database credentials.
Edit the .htaccess file on the live server to your needs.

Visit your site.Clear the cache tables.

Set the correct permissions on settings.php (check status reports for errors) and the desired setUp on sites/default/files etc for file uploads

That's all

Answer (score 0):

The upvoted and accepted solution provided by Pan Chrono will work.

But IMHO the [Backup and migrate](https://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) module is a great help when copying the database, because it will know what tables to exclude (such as cache and sessions), which will remove cruft from the database migration.

Here are my recommended steps to migrate a Drupal site developed locally to a server:

- Revert to the core theme.
- Uninstall and physically remove all modules that you no longer use (if any).
- Create a tar file of the Drupal file system set up you want to migrate to server (i.e. the Drupal root and all files below it.)
- Upload the tar file to the web server and extract it to desired location.
- Make sure the `sites/default` directory and the  `sites/default/files` directory is writable by the web server user.
- Remove `settings.php` from the migrated site. Copy `default.settings.php` to `settings.php`.
- Fire up the browser, type the domain name, and do a clean installation of Drupal as usual.
- Migrate the database using [Backup and migrate](https://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate).
- Check that you still can log in as user #1 (*admin*).  Note that since you've imported the user table, the *admin* username and password is the one used on the site you've just migrated.

Answer (score -1):

> If I copy paste the htdocs folder with ftp in the server, this will
>   work?

Not without the database; You have to import the database too, and then (if you really don't need the contents) delete them manually (there are a lot of ways to do that in bulk, like views bulk operation or a custom module that delete all contents you don't need).

Otherwise you can try [Features](https://drupal.org/project/features) module, where you can export all your fields/settings on a fresh install; but if the site has a bit of complexity I dont know if it will do the trick.

Comment: Then it's better to create it from scratch. Maybe I will need 4-5 hours if I have all the settings ready. Thank you